# Postgres Locking a table inside the function is not working?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION() 
RETURND VOID AS

BEGIN

FOR I IN 1..5
LOOP
LOCK TABLE tbl_Employee1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO tbl_Employee1
VALUES 
(i,'test');

END LOOP;

COMMIT;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

When I select the table it is going into infinty loop means the transaction is not complete. Please help me out ?

Comment: You are locking the table for each and every row. You should put the `lock table` **before** the loop. However the whole function makes no sense to me. There is no need to lock a table if you want to insert and you don't need a self written function to insert a defined number of rows. `generate_series()` will do that for you: `insert into employee1 select i,'test' from generate_series(1,5) i`

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay.. The code above is sample code actually in my function we have update, select, insert and delete statements. We are migrating from oracle to postgres In oracle lock statement is written inside the loop.

Comment: Locking inside a loop was already wrong in Oracle. But I still don't understand **why** you think you need to lock the table. That is bad style - even in Oracle (and again: you don't need a loop like that in Postgres).

Comment: We are putting lock statement to avoid multiple transactions running at same time.

Comment: You should rather define a unique index and handle the errors. But the immediate solution to your is to lock the table **before** the loop.

Comment: OK..I will try putting lock statement before loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has been stripped down so much that it doesn't really make sense any more.

However, you should only lock the table once, not in each iteration of the loop. Plus you can't use `commit` in a function in Postgres, so you have to remove that as well. It's also bad coding style (in Postgres **and** Oracle) to not provide column names for the insert statement.

Immediate solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE Employee1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  FOR I IN 1..5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO Employee1 (id, name)
    VALUES (i,'test');
  END LOOP;
  -- no commit here!    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

The above is needlessly complicated in Postgres and can be implemented **much** more efficiently without a loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ....
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE Employee1 IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  INSERT INTO Employee1 (id, name)
  select i, test
  from generate_series(1,5);

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

---

Locking a table in exclusive mode seems like a bad idea to begin with. In Oracle as well, but in Postgres this might have more [severe implications](https://thebuild.com/blog/2018/08/28/dont-lock-tables-just-dont/). If you want to prevent duplicates in the table, create a unique index (or constraint) and deal with errors. Or use `insert ... on conflict` in Postgres. That will be much more efficient (and scalable) than locking a complete table.

Additionally: `LOCK TABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;` behaves differently in Oracle and Postgres. While Oracle will still allow read only queries on that table, you block every access to it in Postgres - **including** SELECT statements.